# the `addPrimaryClipChangedListener()` listener stops listening when the app is killed

Tags: android, clipboard, clipboardmanager

On some low-memory devices such as Kindle the app is frequently killed by the task manager (even though it introduces a running service). Apparently the listener (not being an Intent) is unregistered automatically by Android as well and is no longer fired. Is there a replacement API which will continue working and monitoring the clipboard even when the app is killed?

The ClipboardManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html does not introduce such API, but perhaps there is some other way?